# Spring @Value default property is not taken when runing JUnit tests

Tags: spring, properties, junit

This is confusing. I have a property outerParameter, which is optionaly given among VM options when starting tomcat. I am using it by the following way in my logic:

```
@Value("${outerParameter:paused}")
private String featureStatus = "active";

public String getFeatureStatus() {
   return featureStatus;
}
```

When starting tomcat without parameter - getFeatureStatus gives "paused", as expected. When starting with defined parameter - gives this parameter value, as expected. 
The confusing part is that when I am runing JUnit tests for getFeatureStatus, it anyway gives me "active" and not the default "paused". The context for tests doesn't contain any `<context:property-placeholder../>` configuration.

I am trying to understand what I am missing, maybe somebody could give me a hand

I found this: 
[Spring @Value annotation not using defaults when property is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698556/spring-value-annotation-not-using-defaults-when-property-is-not-present) 
which could be the answer for my case too. It says "Perhaps initialization of property placeholder configurer fails due to missed properties file, so that placeholders are not resolved".
But if so, why it doesn't fail when starting tomcat without defined outerParameter?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the context file loaded by the tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the property is not loaded in the test case's classpath. Try loading the properties file in the context for test.

Comment: Thanks. But why then when starting tomcat the default values is successfully downloaded? I didn't change anything in tomcat context files, it was a standard installation. Starting tomcat and the project via Intellij IDEA with just set artifact.

Comment: Your tomcat might be loading a context file, that is loading the default properties file successfully. Please share the context file loaded by tomcat. Would be able to help better

Comment: If I understood you right, you asked Tomcat/conf/context.xml. It only contains
     <Context>
        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    </Context>
web.xml can be downloaded by the following link http://www.filedropper.com/web_1

Comment: No. I am asking about the Spring context xml file which, your web application residing in Tomcat, is loading. Please edit the question with the file content instead of uploading. May not be accessible due to various restrictions.

Comment: Sorry, where can I find it?